# Converting a circle's diameter to a straight length?

Tags: geometry

Assume we have a circle:

[image]

That circle's diameter is $m$, if that circle was a string, and we extended the string to a straight line, what would the length be? $m$ or $2m$?

Comment: $\;\pi m=$ the circle's perimeter...?

Comment: In case you have never heard of it before, or if you have a general interest to learn more about it, the ratio of the circumference of the circle (the length of the string if it were straightened to a line) compared to the diameter of the circle is $\pi\approx 3.14159265358979\dots$.  [Read more about $\pi$ here at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi).

Comment: @Joanpemo $m$ is the *diameter* not the radius.  It would be $\pi m$, not $2\pi m$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, good catch.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, in the example I gave out converting a circle string to a straight lined string, how would one equate the length given only the diameter of the circle? Or any other variable relative to the circle?

Comment: If $m=1$ then the circumference is $\pi m \approx 3.14159 \cdot 1 = 3.14159$.  If $m=2$ then the circumference is $\pi m \approx 3.14159\cdot 2 = 6.28208$.  In general if the diameter is $m$ the circumference is $\pi m \approx 3.14159\cdot m$...  Did you check out the link I posted?

Answer (score 1):

The ratio of the length (circumference) of a circle, $C$ to its diameter $m$  is $\pi$ (a Greek letter spelled *pi* and pronounced "pie" in English-speaking countries).  The decimal representation of $\pi$ continues forever without repeating after the decimal point:  $\pi = 3.14159265...$

So if $C/m = \pi$, then $C = m \cdot \pi.$